# What's wrong with CSS styles in Rails 3.1?

Tags: css, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, assets

I switched to the Rails 3.1 and found interesting (for me) stuff - when I update something in my `application.css`, these changes will not be applied after I refresh my browser.  And the same with `application.js`.

How can I get the CSS and JS files to update after I refresh my browser?

Thank you

Comment: What is your environment? I have had a few issues when not running in one of the three default environments. In your case this should be development I think. Also there are a few browsers out there that will just ignore your changed css, mostly the mobile browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you've run `rake assets:precompile`, which caches these files in `public/assets. Run`rake assets:clean` to clear this.

Read the [Asset Pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) guide for more explanation.